# What's the difference between this mentioned list and a certification revocation list?

Tags: crl

I've come across this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8726296) in which the authors mentioned that they don't use a revocation certification list (CRL) since it gives rise to significant costs due to storage and inefficient communication. But then in section 4-F (VEHICLE REVOCATION PHASE), they used a temporary list containing the pseudonyms of revoked vehicles. What's the difference between their temporary list and the CRL?